# НЕ: слитно или раздельно? (2)

Tags: частица-не

Скажите пожалуйста как пишется "не" в данных сочетаниях и почему:
(не)сделано вовремя, (не)одетый малыш

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не сделано вовремя - раздельное написание частицы НЕ с кратким причастием

Неодетый малыш - слитное написание приставки НЕ в причастии при отсутствии зависимых слов.

В данном случае глагольные формы являются именно причастиями, а не прилагательными, так как обозначают признак по действию, а не качественный признак.

Comment: _"В данном случае глагольные формы являются именно причастиями..."_ === Зализняк, наверное, об этом не знал... Иначе бы не назвал в своём словаре слово "неодетый" прилагательным.

Comment: Процесс перехода причастий в прилагательные называется адъективизацией, которая может быть полной (будущий, прирожденный) и временной (испуганный вид – испуганный шумом олень). В большинстве случаев мы имеем дело с временной адъективизацией, главными признаками которой  является утрата зависимых слов и переносное значение.

Comment: Выбор НН или Н делается постоянно, поэтому не имеет смысла считать одиночные глагольные формы прилагательными, например: незамерзший пруд (прил.)  – еще не замерзший пруд (прич.), неодетый ребенок – еще не одетый ребенок. В этих случаях  имеет смысл анализировать только пары  «причастие – отпричастное прилагательное», например: образованная девушка – образованная комиссия, так как отпричастные прилагательные сохраняют статус прилагательного даже при наличии зависимых слов.

Comment: И в заключение  хочется сказать, что нет абсолютных истин, каждое утверждение имеет границы и для одного и того же явления можно принять разные модели  описания  в зависимости от решаемой задачи.  Поэтому мнение великих людей  не всегда бесспорно, и даже Аристотель в чем-то заблуждался (например, считал, что  тяжёлые тела падают быстрее лёгких).

Comment: _Vera: Выбор НН или Н делается постоянно, поэтому не имеет смысла считать одиночные глагольные формы прилагательными, например: незамерзший пруд (прил.) – еще не замерзший пруд (прич.), неодетый ребенок – еще не одетый ребенок._   === Примеры **для выбора "НН или Н"** просто потрясающие!!!

Comment: Ну да, есть небольшая неточность (я имела в виду, что статус отглагольных форм  обычно определяется при выборе Н и НН  или при выборе формы написания НЕ). Надеюсь, что в остальном Вы со мной полностью согласны

Comment: Vera, за ответ проголосовала, но согласна только с 1 частью, а вот НЕОДЕТЫЙ = ГОЛЫЙ, именно качественный признак, поэтому это отглагольное прилагательное. Ваше утверждение ошибочно. Соглашусь со Славой и Зализняком.

Comment: Неодетый - это не то чтобы совсем голый, а не одетый к месту  (без верхнего платья или в домашнем платье). ЛЮБОЕ страд. причастие, образованное от  глагола сов. вида, при отсутствии зависимых слов начинает в той или иной мере обозначать вневременные, непроцессуальные, качественные свойства, но это не значит, что КАЖДОЕ причастие надо называть прилагательным.   (По крайней мере, для орфографии это совершенно ненужное занятие). К примеру,  ненаписанный  роман - это прилагательное, причастие? Ненаписанный – существующий в  мыслях, планах, набросках, тоже качественное свойство.